# Bind mouse movement to keys

Tags: mouse, shortcut-keys

How would I go about binding mousing the mouse in a certain direction, to a certain key (w,a,s,d)? Also if possible making it only work in a certain application would be nice. The reason i want to do this is to play BotW in Cemu and i want to use mouse as movement, without effecting other applications.